# date picker in table cell compress when cell height is reduced to zero

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, datepicker

I am using a datepicker in a table cell. I load the table cell at particular cellIndex. and gives its height to 0. So that on the button click I make it visible and hide accordingly.

The issue coming in this case is. When date picker is shown and i want to hide it. And click the button then picker height is reduced to instantly but table view animates to reduce its cell height to 0.

by user propactive it feels odd that picker compress first and tablecell reduces to 0 later. How should i make them animate so that the cell animation to reduce height will looks good.

I am using begin/end update to make this happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest would be to use the UITableView's builtin animations instead of animating the height yourself. This could be done like so:

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[ indexPathOfYourCell ] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

See [UITableViewRowAnimation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewrowanimation?language=objc) for more animation options.